# How to Call Custom Code Following Successful Spring Security OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've created a OAuth2 Resource Server that accepts and validates JWT tokens and extracts user information from the claims in order to determine user information such as username and authorities.  I've largely done this using [spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) library.

After a user is authenticated, I'd like to call custom code that puts a message on a Kafka stream to indicate that a user has logged in.  Where is the most appropriate place to do this?

I could do this in `OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate`, but I'd have to extend that class and override that method, and then wire it in.  It seems like Spring should have something already in place to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`, which calls the `authenticate` method mentioned in the question, has a member called `eventPublisher`.  Its methods include `publishAuthenticationSuccess`, which is called following a successful authentication.

To tie custom code in to this, create an event listener that gets picked up as a bean by Spring.  Something like this:

```
@Component 
public class MyAuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticationEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent authenticationSuccessEvent) {
        logger.info("User logged in: " + authenticationSuccessEvent.getAuthentication().getName());
    }

}
```